# Mixed effects model: repeated observations in study with one treatment value per group

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a study where I am testing for a linear effect of the continuous variable **treatment** (1-10) on the response variable of **fish abundance** repeatedly observed in **lakes** (A-J). My concern is that there is one treatment level per lake and each treatment level only occurs at that one lake. Dummy data is shown below.

Is it valid for me to analyze this data with:

```
lmer(fish.abundance~treatment+(1|lake),data=dat)
```

?

(Averaging values within lakes and fitting a simple linear model is not an option in the real analysis because I will also be accounting for seasonal trends in fish abundance, e.g.,

```
gamm(fish.abundance~treatment+s(day.of.year),random=list(lake=~1),data=dat)
```

)

```
treatment   lake    fish.abundance
1   A   1
1   A   2
1   A   3
2   B   2
2   B   3
2   B   4
3   C   3
3   C   4
3   C   5
4   D   4
4   D   5
4   D   6
5   E   5
5   E   6
5   E   7
6   F   6
6   F   7
6   F   8
7   G   7
7   G   8
7   G   9
8   H   8
8   H   9
8   H   10
9   I   9
9   I   10
9   I   11
10  J   10
10  J   11
10  J   12
```

Comment: This should be moved to CrossValidated as it is a stats question and not a coding question. That said, you won't be able to differentiate between a treatment or lake effect.

Comment: @BWilliams is right.   You can't do better than `gam(fish.abundance~treatment+s(day.of.year)+lake,data=dat)` and admitting that your inference is limited (i.e. you're ascribing any differences among lakes to the treatment)

Comment: Thank you for the answers and apologies for posting in the wrong forum. I wonder if an alternative approach might be to reduce the resolution of the treatment (e.g., lumping treatment values of 1-3, 4-6, & 7-10 into new categories of 1, 2, & 3). This would create a nested design, with multiple lakes for each level of the treatment.

Comment: I think that might work.